# Why is dealloc not called on a brand new project (xcode 3.1.4)?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, dealloc

I am starting to learn iPhone programming and this should be apparently a very easy question. I work in xcode 3.1.4. Now, when I create a new project of a window-based application and modify dealloc (in the AppDelegate.m file) so that it actually makes a print statement on the console, I actually can *not* see that statement. So, my question is why?

So that I can avoid obvious answers, the modified dealloc is:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Dealloc is called");
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Is this strange or not?

Originally I had posted similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322586/how-to-assign-the-maincontroller-and-a-custom-view-to-an-app-with-a-single-windo), but now I know that the real problem is the one I describe here. Moderators, feel free to delete my other thread. My apologies.

Comment: Why do you use so old Xcode and don't go for newer?

Comment: @AleksejsMjaliks:I use this version of Xcode for two main reasons. I am running Leopard. Hence, any version above 3.1.4 requires >= Snow Leopard. That is one upgrade I should make. Of course if I am going to upgrade, I should probably go for Lion. That is now either two upgrades in a row, or keep a backup and then format/upgrade without having to go through the intermediate step of Snow Leopard. In a few months a new OS is expected; so I should probably go for that instead. The other reason that I am using xcode 3.1.4 is b/c this way I will write apps that are running on iPhone3 (OS v. 4.2.1).

Comment: @MightyMouse You don't need such an old xcode for the 2nd reason.  You can target any ios version you want as long as you don't use features that it doesn't support.

Comment: You are right @borrrden. However, all the guides for newer versions of xcode are very likely to exploit new features _without_ even saying that certain things do not work on earlier versions of OS. So, I am just playing it safe here. Familiarizing myself with the language and as many features as possible on "old" phones and once I have a first extended tour on all the features, then, yes I will move on to a newer version of xcode. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @MightyMouse XCode 4 has a gigantic laundry list of changes from XCode 3, so don't get too used to XCode 3 style.  The documentation of any function will indicate which iOS it is available from (This can be viewed directly from xcode in version 4) so I don't think you need to worry too much about that ;).

Comment: Thanks for everything @borrrden. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The appDelegate won't be deallocated until the application ends, at which point it's too late to see messages on the console.

Also, for any new projects, you should use ARC anyway, which removes the need to call dealloc in a lot of cases.

Comment: @Dave Wood: Why is it too late to see application messages on the console? _That is the question really._ dealloc is just another method and it has an NSLog command. From what I understand ARC is not supported on my version of Xcode. Moreover, please see my comment above on Aleksejs Mjaliks's question on why I am running Xcode 3.1.4.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that NSLog is not available when this dealloc is called.  The App delegate is the last thing to be deallocated in your project when the program is finished.

Comment: Thank you @borrrden. Why would NSLog be not available by then though?

Comment: Because your application is no longer running at that point, so (I assume) it has no reference to the console anymore.  It would be like piping a message to /dev/null on a Unix system.  The data would just get discarded.

Comment: Another theory is that since the application has exited its run loop, it has posted the data to a buffer but the buffer never gets written.  The inner workings of NSLog are a bit cryptic to me.  However, the only way for the app delegate to be deallocated is for the application to terminate, so either way it is going to release its memory.

Comment: Thank you @borrrden. I also realized a few more things while digging into it. For instance I realized that UIApplicationMain never returns a value and this appears to be the case in the documentation. On the bright side, apparently instruments is a good companion to check for possible memory leaks. In any case, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Its not getting called because your application might be running by then. And when it is called your application might have been terminated. I agree with borrrden's point that appdelegate's dealloc function is the last thing to be called. If you want to understand retai/release, alloc/dealloc, try using xcode 3.2.6 and if you want to use ARC try xcode 4.2 with ios5.

Comment: I am new in iPhone programming, but not new in programming in general. So no, I think I have understood the concepts of retain/release, alloc/dealloc. I am really asking why I do not see the message on the console. _That is frustrating._ Moreover, I can not use an Xcode version above 3.1.4 for the reasons that I mention in my opening post. Thanks anyway.